# How to pass JSON data into extJS store model.

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid where I bind my store in this manner.

```
bind: {
    store:'{myStoreViewModel}'
},
```

Now in myStoreViewModel I defined like this.

```
myStoreViewModel:{
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'myUrl',
        timeout: 240000,
        paramsAsJson: true,
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: 'myLoad',
    }
},
```

Here I am getting my `serviceStatus` failure. Then i further investigate this with normal Ajax.

Here is my normal Ajax

```
myNormalAjax : function(myJSON){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'retrievemsgsummary.do',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: ProcessConstants.VALBIZDT_TIMEOUT,
        jsonData: myJSON,
        success: function(response) {
            var responseText = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            if (responseText.serviceStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
                this.messageSummaryDetails(this,responseText);
            } 
        },
        failure: function(response) {

        },
        scope: this

    });
            },
```

Here I am passing `jsonData` and serviceStatus is coming sucess.

then In my viewModel also I am trying pass jsonData but no luck. This how i am passing jsonData there.

```
dataObj : function(myJSONDATA){
    var myStoreStore = this.getViewModel().getStore('myStoreViewModel');
        myStoreStore.proxy.jsonData = myJSONDATA;
}
```

Can anybody suggest how to bind my store for my grid.

**

Answer (score 2):

You can pass additional params (extra params) to store's proxy either using the proxy's [extraParams](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Server.html#cfg-extraParams) config at store/proxy definition, or later in the life cycle using [setExtraparam](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Server.html#method-setExtraParam) or [setExtraparams](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Server.html#placeholder-accessor-setExtraParams) methods. So, in your case, it could be something like this:

```
dataObj : function(myJSONDATA){
    var myStoreStore = this.getViewModel().getStore('myStoreViewModel');
    myStoreStore.getProxy().setExtraParams(myJSONDATA);
}
```